# Javascript setting input radio value also sets "checked" in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a form where I set the value of an `input type="radio"` pair using Javascript.  However, I've noticed that Chrome handles it differently from Firefox and IE, and, although I can work around it, I would like to know -- *why is this happening?*

Here's example code (or see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ps46opy3/1/)

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="xyzzy" value="yes"/> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="xyzzy" value="no"/> No
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.form1.xyzzy.value='yes';
</script>
```

In Chrome this will set the value AND check the radio for "yes", which is what I want.  However in Firefox/IE it sets the value, but does not "check" the radio.  In that case, when the form is submitted, the value is not actually POSTed.

I can fix this problem by adding `document.form1.xyzzy[0].checked=true`, but it seems a bit redundant to me that you'd have to set BOTH the value AND checked properties, which should go hand-in-hand.

Is this a bug in Firefox/IE, or a feature in Chrome, or...?